# Put dynamically sized UITextView into UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, uitextview

I'm very new at this and I'm working on a basic master-detail application. When you tap a table view cell, a view is presented that contains a UILabel at the top for the title of the item, a UIImage to illustrate the item and a UITextView to provide a description of the item. At the moment, the text is scrollable, whilst the label and image stay in place.

Is it possible to add everything to a UIScrollView so that the entire view, complete with image and label, will scroll at once? The information in the text view is predetermined and cannot be edited, but the amount of text in each will differ so the text view will need to resize itself (height wise) to fit the text - will this cause an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the TextView height dynamically using the below code

in .m file `viewDidLoad` method add the below lines

```
yourTextView=[[UITextView alloc]init];

txtView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, yourTextView.frame.size.width, [self textSize:YOURTEXT]+20);

yourTextView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

yourTextView.userInteractionEnabled=NO;

yourTextView.font=[UIFont fontWithName:yourFont size:12];

yourScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320,yourTextView.frame.origin.y+yourTextView.frame.size.height+10);
```

After that add this function.

```
-(CGFloat) textSize:(NSString *)dataString
{

    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:yourFont size:12];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(yourTextView.frame.size.width-10, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize = [dataString sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    return labelSize.height+20;
}
```

Comment: I managed to get the text view to resize itself with the method '[self.textView sizeToFit]', but now I need to add it to a scroll view and by extension resize the scroll view also, as you have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to edit the text, use a `UILabel` instead. Make sure to set `numberOfLines` to either `0` (no limit) or a number of your choosing.

If you want to size the content yourself, you can use `textRectForBounds` on the `UILabel`.

Comment: If I use a UILabel for a detail view that also contains a picture, the text often is truncated. How do I set the size of the scroll view to accommodate the size of the label? The label wouldn't be the same size each time as each detail view would have a different amount of text.

Comment: You can use `textRectForBounds` to calculate the size and then call `setContentSize`.